# MPI_Bcast returns EXIT CODE: 139 on large char arrays

Tags: arrays, c++11, char, mpi, valgrind

I would appreciate, if you could help me troubleshoot the following situation.

I broadcast (on localhost) a char array in 2 consecutive steps:

1. MPI_Bcast the size of the array
2. MPI_Bcast the array itself

This is done via dynamic process spawning. The data communication works *well* until the size of the array exceeds (roughly) the number of 8375000 elements. That is 8.375Mb of data, which seems quite small according to available documentation. As far as I read in other posts, MPI supports up to 2^31 elements. After I exceed the 8375000 elements, I receive an MPI error with `EXIT CODE: 139`.

For that I test the code on **valgrind**. The summary does not indicate something worrisome, but I receive various MPI related errors starting with `Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)`. Herewith the tail of the log.

```
...
==15125== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==15125==    at 0x5B83327: writev (writev.c:26)
==15125==    by 0x8978FF1: MPL_large_writev (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x8961D4B: MPID_nem_tcp_iStartContigMsg (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x8939E15: MPIDI_CH3_RndvSend (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x895DD69: MPID_nem_lmt_RndvSend (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x8945FE9: MPID_Send (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x88B1D84: MPIC_Send (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x886EC08: MPIR_Bcast_inter_remote_send_local_bcast (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x87C28F2: MPIR_Bcast_impl (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x87C3183: PMPI_Bcast (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125==    by 0x50B9CF5: QuanticBoost::Calculators::Exposures::Mpi::dynamic_mpi_master(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, QuanticBoost::WorkflowContext&) (in /home/ubuntu/Documents/code/quanticboostnew-build/release/lib/libCppLib.so)
==15125==    by 0x5140CBA: QuanticBoost::MpiExposureSpawnTask::execute(QuanticBoost::WorkflowContext&) (in /home/ubuntu/Documents/code/quanticboostnew-build/release/lib/libCppLib.so)
==15125==  Address 0x1ffefff524 is on thread 1's stack
==15125==  in frame #3, created by MPIDI_CH3_RndvSend (???:)
==15125==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==15125==    at 0x8939D70: MPIDI_CH3_RndvSend (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==15125== 
==15125== 
==15125== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15125==     in use at exit: 184 bytes in 6 blocks
==15125==   total heap usage: 364,503 allocs, 364,497 frees, 204,665,377 bytes allocated
==15125== 
==15125== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15125==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15125==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15125==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15125==    still reachable: 184 bytes in 6 blocks
==15125==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15125== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==15125== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==15125== 
==15125== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15125== ERROR SUMMARY: 15 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

> Could you help me identifying the vagrind errors and solve the MPI failure with code 139?

---

Below I share minimum code snippets from the **master** and **worker** code, as well as the output with the **error** code.

Code snippet (**master**):

```
std::cout << "Spawning "<< dynamic_procs << " " << worker_path.string() <<std::endl;

MPI_Comm_spawn(
                worker_path.string().c_str(),
                MPI_ARGV_NULL,
                dynamic_procs,
                info,
                0,
                MPI_COMM_SELF, //intra-communication
                &intercomm,  //inter-communication
                MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

        
std::cout << "\n________________ MASTER: MPI spawning starts _________________ \n" << std::endl;

// I normally send the size of the char array in the 1st Bcast
// and the array itself in a 2nd Bcast
//
// but MPI starts failing somewhere beyond 8.375e6 elements 
// though I expect that happening after 2^31 array elements, or not???

//I test the limits of the array size by overriding manually
int in_str_len=8.375e6; //Until this size it all works
//int in_str_len=8.376e6; //This does NOT work
//int in_str_len=8.3765e6; //This does NOT work and so on
      
MPI_Bcast(
                &in_str_len,    //void* data,
                1,              //int count,
                MPI_INT,        //MPI_Datatype datatype,
                MPI_ROOT,       //int use MPI_ROOT not own set root!
                intercomm       //MPI_Comm communicator
        );

//Initialize a test buffer      
std::string s (in_str_len, 'x');        //It works
//char d[in_str_len+1];                 //It works

/*
 * The 2nd MPI_Bcast will send the data to all nodes 
 */
MPI_Bcast(
                s.data(),       //void* data,
                in_str_len,     //int count,
                MPI_BYTE,       //MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_BYTE,MPI_CHAR work
                MPI_ROOT,       //int use MPI_ROOT not own set root!
                intercomm       //MPI_Comm communicator
               );
```

Code snippet (**worker**):

```
std::cout << "I am in a spawned process " << rank << "/" << dynamic_procs
          << " from host " << name << std::endl;

int in_str_len;

//Receive stream size;
MPI_Bcast(
    &in_str_len,    //void* data,
    1,              //int count,
    MPI_INT,        //MPI_Datatype datatype,
    0,              //int root,
    parent          //MPI_Comm communication with parent (not MPI_COMM_WORLD)
    );

std::cout << "1st MPI_Bcast received len: "<< in_str_len * 1e-6<<"Mb" << std::endl;
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); //Tested with and without the barrier

char data[in_str_len+1];

std::cout << "Create char array for 2nd MPI_Bcast with length: "<< in_str_len << std::endl;
    
MPI_Bcast(
    data,           //void* data,
    in_str_len,     //int count,
    MPI_BYTE,       //MPI_Datatype datatype,
    0,              //int root,
    parent          //MPI_Comm communication with parent (not MPI_COMM_WORLD)
    );

std::cout << "2nd MPI_Bcast received data: " << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
```

**Error** received with the large array:

```
Spawning 3 /home/ubuntu/Documents/code/build/release/bin/mpi_worker

________________ MASTER: MPI spawning starts _________________ 

I am in a spawned process 1/3 from host ip-172-31-30-254
I am in a spawned process 0/3 from host ip-172-31-30-254
I am in a spawned process 2/3 from host ip-172-31-30-254

1st MPI_Bcast received len: 8.3765Mb
1st MPI_Bcast received len: 8.3765Mb
1st MPI_Bcast received len: 8.3765Mb

Create char array for 2nd MPI_Bcast with length: 8376500
Create char array for 2nd MPI_Bcast with length: 8376500
Create char array for 2nd MPI_Bcast with length: 8376500

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 9690 RUNNING AT localhost
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
```

PS: Let me know if you need any extra info or further editing on my post.

Comment: What is your stack limit? 8Mb is big if you haven’t raised the limit.

Comment: $ ulimit -s
8192

Comment: Shall I ask about the remaining valgring errors on this post ? I need to completely remove the Spawn routine to fully get rid off the errors.

Comment: Yes if you’ve resolved the stack space issue by using the heap and your exe seems to run to completion correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in your error message. Learn to read error messages!

1. First of all it says something about uninitialized data. That is true. On the non-root processes you are accessing a buffer that in a way "does not exist yet". I'll spare you the technicalities but you can google for "page instantiation". Basically, the array does not exist yet in memory if you haven't initialized it.
2. But the real problem is: "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation"

You create you array with `char data[somethingbig]`. That is

1. Not language standard (actually, it is in C99, and then again deprecated in C11; basically: don't do that.)
2. Data on the stack and your stack is of limited size.

So: any array of any macroscopic size, use `malloc`.

Oh, and you tag this "c++". In that case only use `std::vector` for large arrays. There is no reason to use anything else, and as you have seen, plenty not to.

Comment: Your answer helped already a lot, but please help me understand something.

First, I am sending an initialized string from the master (see the fill constructor `std::string s (in_str_len, 'x');`). However, your comment motivated me to use initialized string ( `std::string received(in_str_len, '.');` )on the worker too and now it all works! I can send 1Gb of string without a problem. So, does this mean that the workers' data are transmitted too? I thought the workers only receive with Bcast.

Second, I still get the same valgrind errors. Can you give a hint here?

Comment: My comment about `char data[whatever]` was indeed about the worker code. 1. Even though the worker processes receive the data, the array has to be instantiated first, which is done by your constructor. 2. In `Bcast` the non-root processes only receive data. Not sure why you think they would be transmitting. Valgrind: add (do not edit; the original question can be valuable to other people) your improved code and error msg and I'll take another look.

Comment: Oh, I may have confused you: I said that the bcast transmitted an uninitialized array. I read your code too quickly. No, the workers do not transmit.

Comment: It is quite clear now. I assumed (based on similar paradigms) the received data are allocated inside the Bcast, but no. This is something I keep. I will reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

The error (EXIT CODE:139) in the initial post comes form the workers code

`char data[in_str_len+1];`

which needs to be initialized as done in the master, for instance by:

`std::string received(in_str_len, '.');`

As such, I can **transmit** up to 2147483647 string size.

---

Though I am still getting valgrind errors while everything works as expected. The errors relate to `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation`.

```
...

==13556== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==13556==    at 0x5A7E327: writev (writev.c:26)
==13556==    by 0x8873FF1: MPL_large_writev (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x885CD4B: MPID_nem_tcp_iStartContigMsg (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x87EEDD3: MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_Close (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x8850A3D: MPID_nem_handle_pkt (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x88627E7: state_commrdy_handler (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x8862CFB: MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x88519BC: MPIDI_CH3I_Progress (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x87FFBC4: FreeNewVC (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x8802AFE: MPIDI_Comm_accept (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x883EDF4: MPID_Comm_accept (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==    by 0x87EE4D0: MPIDI_Comm_spawn_multiple (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556==  Address 0x1ffefff128 is on thread 1's stack
==13556==  in frame #3, created by MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_Close (???:)
==13556==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13556==    at 0x87EED00: MPIDI_CH3_PktHandler_Close (in /usr/lib/libmpi.so.12.1.6)
==13556== 
==13556== 
==13556== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13556==     in use at exit: 184 bytes in 6 blocks
==13556==   total heap usage: 317,171 allocs, 317,165 frees, 144,996,884 bytes allocated
==13556== 
==13556== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13556==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13556==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13556==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13556==    still reachable: 184 bytes in 6 blocks
==13556==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13556== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13556== 
==13556== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13556== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Such errors exist even when there is no MPI communication and they completely disappear if I dont invoke the MPI Spawn. So it seems they might be related with MPI internal initializations.